# Parse HTML table into Xamarin usable data format

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite-net

I'm writing a Xamarin app which has a function to grab some data from an HTML table. I want to then display this data somehow in my app; at the moment I'm thinking a ListView is the way to go but I'm open to alternatives.

In my web-scraping prototype I simply grabbed the HTML table using HtmlAgility and then iterated over the rows and inserted them into a `DataTable`:

```cs
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    int counter = 1;

                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
                    {
                        switch (counter)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                dr["Column1"] = cell.InnerText;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                dr["Column2"] = cell.InnerText;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                dr["Column3"] = cell.InnerText;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                dr["Column4"] = cell.InnerText;
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                dr["Column5"] = cell.InnerText;
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                dr["Column6"] = cell.InnerText;
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                dr["Column7"] = cell.InnerText;
                                break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
```

I don't think using a DataTable is very sensible for a mobile application (or even possible?).

Currently I'm thinking I should use SQLite-Net to create a local database and insert records from my HTML table into my database table.

Is this a sensible approach, and how would I go about doing that with SQLite?

Comment: I would only use SQLite if there is a need for persistent storage, or a LOT of data to deal with, otherwise I would probably just store them in memory.  In either case, I'd create a custom model class to store the data.

Comment: Can you recommend/point me in the direction of resources to learn about storing data in a class? I'm familiar with storing single variables at class level (e.g. public int ID { get; set; }) but I'm not sure how I'd store "rows" of data?

Comment: your class models one row of data.  Use a List or other container to store multiple rows, like List<MyClass>

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be.

First, declare an object to represent each row of the Listview,

Example:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Element1 {get; set;}
    public string Element2 {get; set;}
}
```

Here, you will have each row of Element,with the different data to be displayed within the columns in your listview.

```
public class Element
{
    public string Element1 {get; set;}
    public string Element2 {get; set;}
}
```

Then, in your ViewModel, declare the List to store the items.

```
public ObvervableCollection<Element> MyItems = new ObservableCollection();
```

After this, in your Page.xaml, declare a listview, note the Header, to display the Table Headers, and then, in the viewcell, the elements to be displayed

```
<ListView x:Name=”MainListView” ItemsSource={Binding MyItems}>  
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>  
        <DataTemplate>  
            <Grid>  
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Label Text=”Column1" Grid.Column="0"/>

                   <Label Text=”Column2" Grid.Column="1"/>
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>  
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>  
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
        <DataTemplate>  
            <ViewCell>  
               <Grid>  
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text=”{Binding Element1}" Grid.Column="0"/>

                <Label Text=”{Binding Element2}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
            </ViewCell>  
        </DataTemplate>  
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm still pretty new to Xamarin so I'll need to do some further research but this looks like a good starting point.

Comment: So I've been playing around with this and I've encountered a few issues. Firstly, this: `public ObservableCollection<Element> MyItems = new ObservableCollection();` throws a warning "Using the generic type ObservableCollection<T> requires 1 type arguments". Should that say "public ObservableCollection<Element> MyItems = new ObservableCollection<Element>();"? Secondly, I appear to need a constructor in my "Element" class, is that correct?

Comment: Here is a tutorial about observable collection and listview itemsSource: https://lalorosas.com/blog/xamarin-forms-mvvm-observablecollectiont

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.